# Allow MDB Downloads in IIS7

Tags: ms-access, iis-7, download

Currently if I am hosting an Access .MDB file to allow users to download, IIS7 is throwing a 404 error.  I know the file is there and the permissions are fine.  It appears to be a Handler issue, but I cannot figure out how to change the handler to allow downloading of MDB file.  I assume I need to add something to the Handlers section of the web.config, but I am unsure of the syntax.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Or, if you don't want to modify a system-wide configuration file, you could add the following lines to that section in your web.config:

```
<remove fileExtension=".mdb" />
<add fileExtension=".mdb" allowed="true"/>
```

For example your Web.config should be similar to this:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <fileExtensions allowUnlisted="true" >
          <remove fileExtension=".mdb" />
          <add fileExtension=".mdb" allowed="true"/>
        </fileExtensions>
     </requestFiltering>
   </security>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Also see http://www.adamwlewis.com/articles/iis-7-not-serving-files-4047-error.

Comment: Excellent...thanks for the added info.  I did need a server-wide change though.

Answer (score 3):

OK, found it.

Just need to remove the following line:

```
<add fileExtension=".mdb" allowed="false" />
```

in the "requestFiltering" section from the \Windows\System32\inetserv\config\applicationHost.config file.