# I cannot download certain file types from website. In particular .frm, .frx, .mgf. Getting HTTP 404 error

Tags: html, browser

I cannot download certain file types from website. In particular .frm, .frx, .mgf. Getting error: HTTP Error 404 - File or directory not found. I added these file types in IIS as local, it did not help. Can I add any kind of code to the webpage to allow downloading of such files?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allow MDB Downloads in IIS7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066981/allow-mdb-downloads-in-iis7)

Comment: 404 means items not found meaning you must have the directory target wrong or the files are not accepted by the system..

Comment: @Machavity i have it allowed="true" but still get 404 error

Answer (score 0):

All need to be done on the website hosting server, not on downloading computer. Daaahhh. Make sure your hosting account was switched to IIS7.

web.config file need to be created (can be done in Notepad) and placed in the root directory of the website.

web.config file for allowing download of .mgf files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
   <staticContent>
     <mimeMap fileExtension=".mgf" mimeType="text/plain" />
   </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```